# Solving memory issues for huge dataset in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, imagenet

i have this code which uses Keras 2.0.1 and it's generators for image recognition by performing deep learning. This code currently works fine with 1500 images when run on a GPU but when i start evaluating it with 50k images then i get memory issues.i am using flow from directory for reading images and predict_generator for getting predictions and probabilities. Below is the error that i get and the code that i am using:

ERROR:

```
2018-01-08 12:28:49.940361: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:955] failed to alloc 17179869184 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-01-08 12:28:49.968880: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 17179869184
```

CODE

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from keras import applications
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten

top_model_weights_path = '/home/rehan/ethnicity.071217.23-0.28.hdf5'
path = "/home/rehan/countries/pakistan/guys/test/"
img_width, img_height = 139, 139

confidence = 0.8

model = applications.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                                       input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

print("base pretrained model loaded")



validation_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow_from_directory(path, target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                                        batch_size=6,shuffle=False)

print("generator built")


features = model.predict_generator(validation_generator)

print("features found")

model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(3, 3, 1536)))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)
print("top model loaded")
prediction_proba = model.predict_proba(features)
prediction_classes = model.predict_classes(features)
print(prediction_proba)
print(prediction_classes)
print("original file names")
print(validation_generator.filenames)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a open issue on the keras github page related to this: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5835

Maybe you could try to load the image as float32 instead of doubles/float64 (the default), that would halve your memory needs.

Comment: where can i change this option? flow from directory has no such arguments.

Comment: Something like ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=lambda x: x.astype('float32'), rescale=1./255)

Comment: That's bad. Maybe you could build your own image loader until the bug is solved. Old DL code uses custom Image loader methods for training/testing.